# How to return a list of arangodb documents that match an item in a list?

Tags: python, arangodb, aql

Using python and AQL I am trying to return a list of vertices  that match any item in a given list. The current result from the db I am getting is an empty list.

The python equivalent would be this:

```
list_of_terms = ["yellow", "blue"]
list_of_vertices = ["yellow", "green"]

terms = [term for term in list_of_terms if term in list_of_vertices]

print(terms)
```

An example of one AQL query I tried.

```
For doc in some_collection
    FILTER doc.name==@list_of_terms
    RETURN doc
```

And the full full function using `python-arango`

```
bind_vars = {
    "lookup_terms": list_of_terms
   }
```

Thanks in advance

```
qry = "FOR doc IN `{0}` FILTER doc.name== @lookup_terms AND doc.text != null RETURN doc".format(collection_nm)
print(qry)
cursor = db.aql.execute(
    qry,
    bind_vars=bind_vars,
    batch_size=10,
    count=True
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `IN` operator:

```
FOR doc IN some_collection
    FILTER doc.name IN @list_of_terms
    RETURN doc
```

From the documentation:

> `IN`: test if a value is contained in an array

See https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operators.html#range-operator

Your python code would then become:

```py
bind_vars = {
    "lookup_terms": list_of_terms
} 
qry = "FOR doc IN `{0}` FILTER doc.name IN @lookup_terms AND doc.text != null RETURN doc".format(collection_nm)
print(qry)
cursor = db.aql.execute(
    qry,
    bind_vars=bind_vars,
    batch_size=10,
    count=True
)
```